# SQL count zero even when there are no records?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008

I have 2 tables

1. PS

   Columns: PS_ID(PK), AID(FK), PS_Vendor
2. System

   Columns: System_ID(PK), AID(FK), Sys_Prod

The two tables are connected thru `PS.AID = System.AID`

I have to find the count of `PS_Vendors` for each `SYS_Product` and the total for each `Sys_product`.

My output has to look like:

```
PS_Vendor Sys_product Count Total
 ABC         A         2      10  
 ABC         B         5      20       
 ABC         C         0      15
 XYZ         A         3      10
 XYZ         B         0      20
 XYZ         C         12     15
```

I created a view called `PS_system_View`:

```
select * from system
left outer join ps
on ps.aid=system.aid
```

I am having trouble combining these

```
select B.ps_vendor, A.sys_product, B.Count,A.Total from 

--To get the total:

select sys_product, sum(total) as Total from

(select sys_product, ps_vendor, sum(case when sys_product is not null then 1 else 0 end) as total

 from PS_System_view

)A

group by sys_product

left join

(

--To get the count:

select sys_product, ps_vendor, sum(case when ps_vendor is not null then 1 else 0 end) as count from
 PS_System_view

where ps_vendor is not null and sys_product is not null

)B on B.sys_product=A.Sys_product
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_join#Left_outer_join

Comment: Show some sample data. I don't know how the tables are related and where `count` and `total` come from. You might think about posting some sample data, and a query you've actually tried, at http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: What is AID? Glad you got only one of those....

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense.  Why does XYZ have "D" but not "C" and ABC have "C" not "D"?

Comment: Could somebody please suggest as to how I can solve this problem.thanks